# Heat equation to mixed boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm studying heat equations,

I've more or less understood how to solve them when given two boundary conditions $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$  and when given $\frac{\partial u(0,t)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(L,t)}{\partial x}=0$, for $0<x<L$.

My problem starts when asked to solve for a mix of the two:

$u(L,t)=\frac{\partial u(0,t)}{\partial x}=0$,

The method described in the book details using separation of variables to define $u=X(x)T(t)$ to arrive at $X''-\lambda X= 0 $

Setting $\lambda=-k^2$ gives:

$X(x)=Asin(kx) + Bcos(kx)$

But somehow applying the boundary conditions gives:

$X(x)=\cos(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L})$

Would someone mind explaining how this is done? I get $A=0$ from the insulating boundary condition and $B \cos(kL)=0 => k=\frac {n \pi}{L}$ from the other BC. Not sure where the $(2n+1)$ is coming from...

Answer (score 1):

> $B \cos(kL)=0 => k=\frac {n \pi}{L}$

This is false. The cosine function has zeros at $\pi/2,\pi/2+\pi,\pi/2+2\pi,\cdots$, i.e. at $\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's too late in the night for me to be doing math.